# ¿Que hace la funcion DECODE en PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, condiciones, toad

Que hay amigos, tengo esa pregunta, en si ¿cual es la función/proposito de un **DECODE**?

```
SELECT PART_NO, PROD_VERSION, TO_CHAR(ORIGINAL_START_DATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'), DECODE(OWNER, 'PRODUCTION_1', 'PRODUCTION_2', 'PRODUCTION_3', 'PRODUCTION_4', 'PRODUCTION_5', 'PRODUCTION_6', OWNER) LOTTEST
```

Tengo entendido que es una especie de sentencia **IF-THEN-ELSE**, pero no logro figurar como.

Comment: Desde la documentación de *Oracle* [justo aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm), que indica que va a comparar la expresión con cada valor de búsqueda uno por uno, en caso de que la expresión sea igual a la búsqueda entonces se retorna un resultado.........

Comment: Si eso mismo capte de la documentación, entonces SUPONGAMOS que el valor que guarda **OWNER** (mi expresion) es `"Production_1"` va a retornar `"Production_2"` por la evaluación? y si **ninguna** evaluacion es correcta, retorna el valor que hay dentro del **OWNER** que esta al final de las comparaciones (que seria `"Production_1"`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algo que se aprende por experiencia es que la forma en que dispongas tu código puede proveerte información , en este caso:

```
SELECT PART_NO, PROD_VERSION, TO_CHAR(ORIGINAL_START_DATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'), DECODE(OWNER, 'PRODUCTION_1', 'PRODUCTION_2', 'PRODUCTION_3', 'PRODUCTION_4', 'PRODUCTION_5', 'PRODUCTION_6', OWNER) LOTTEST
```

es una consulta en una única línea, pero si la observas con esta indentación, verás que es un poco más clara:

```
SELECT PART_NO
  , PROD_VERSION
  , TO_CHAR(ORIGINAL_START_DATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
  , DECODE(OWNER, 'PRODUCTION_1', 'PRODUCTION_2'
                , 'PRODUCTION_3', 'PRODUCTION_4'
                , 'PRODUCTION_5', 'PRODUCTION_6'
                                        , OWNER) LOTTEST
```

Tomará el valor de `OWNER` ysi su valor es `'PRODUCTION_1'` lo convertirá en `'PRODUCTION_2'`, si es `'PRODUCTION_3'` lo convertirá en `'PRODUCTION_4'`, si es `'PRODUCTION_5'` lo convertirá en `'PRODUCTION_6'` y en caso de que no  sea ninguno de esos, lo dejará con su valor original.